# map cannot find data by using vector content

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector

```
for(iter=net_lib.begin() ; iter!=net_lib.end() ; iter++){
    for(int i=0 ; i < iter->size(); i++){
        iter_m = block_lib.begin();
        iter_m = block_lib.find((*iter)[i]);
        if( iter_m != block_lib.end() ){index = iter_m->second.infile_order;cout<<"here\n";}
    }
}
```

The above code result shows that map cannot find  `(*iter)[i]` data store in the vector.
And the below is data structures I use

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <map>
#include <utility>

class block{
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    int width;
    int height;
    string name;
    char type;    //T terminal , B block
    int infile_order;
};

int main(){
map< string , block> block_lib ;
vector<string> temp;
vector< vector<string> > net_lib;
vector< vector<string> >::const_iterator iter;
map< string , block>::const_iterator iter_m;
block a,b;
a.x=0; a.y=0; b.x=0; b.y=0;
a.width=50; a.height=10;
b.width=50; b.height=10;
a.infile_order=0;
b.infile_order=1;
a.name = "bk11";
b.name = "bk12a";
block_lib["bk11"]=a;
block_lib["bk12a"]=b;
temp.push_back("bk11");
temp.push_back("bk12a");
net_lib.push_back(temp);
temp.push_back("bk11");
net_lib.push_back(temp);
    for(iter=net_lib.begin() ; iter!=net_lib.end() ; iter++){
    for(int i=0 ; i < iter->size(); i++){
        int index=0;
        iter_m = block_lib.begin();
        iter_m = block_lib.find((*iter)[i]);
        if( iter_m != block_lib.end() ){index = iter_m->second.infile_order;cout<<"here\n";}
    }
}
```

BTW, code will be segmentation fault when i replace `(*iter)[i]` by string `"GND"`, like block_lib.find("GND") will show "here" in the command window but cause segmentation fault.

This test code should be able to compile and run, but it is just a simplified version.
The original version use iostream input file load into net_lib and block_lib. 
My problem is when block_lib and net_lib grow bigger, it will never go into the
    if( iter_m != block_lib.end() ){index = iter_m->second.infile_order;cout<<"here\n";}
part, and I need this code to go into this part.

This is my source code 
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7fiOFHx2DbvYVZ4UGY2UXQ3cTQ&usp=sharing
and I use gcc 4.1.2 compiler.

And this part is in the function cost_cal.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE] that reproduces your problem.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. It prints "Here" when it *finds* iter[i], not when it can't find it.

Comment: Your code, when fixed to compile, prints out "here" 5 times just as you would expect: http://ideone.com/mIBL0e

Comment: Try to clarify your question -- Are you asking why it segfaults with (*iter)[i] where i= "GND" ? Or are you getting a compilation errorr, or does the find not yield the result you expected?